# Raspberry pi gpio pins are stuck in the "in" and "high" mode

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gpio, gpiozero

I am running Raspbian Stretch on a Raspberry Pi 2. I was trying to build a basic obstacle avoidance rover and ran into a problem with the motors. 
Schematic found here:

[image]

I don't have the dc-dc converter and I have a LED with a 330 ohm resistor connected to pin 17.

I was using this code to run it:

```
from gpiozero import LED
from gpiozero import Motor
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep

# prereqs
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
Motorbin = 5
Motorbout = 6
GPIO.setup(Motor2in,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(Motor2out,GPIO.OUT)

led = LED(17)

for i in range(2):
    led.on()
    sleep(0.5)
    led.off()
    sleep(0.5)



# motors are going to start running now

motora = Motor(27, 22)
motora.forward()
sleep(5)
motora.backward()
sleep(5)
motora.stop()

for i in range(2):
    led.on()
    sleep(0.5)
    led.off()
    sleep(0.5)

motorb = (5, 6)
motorb.forward()
sleep(5)
motorb.backward()
sleep(5)
motorb.stop()

GPIO.cleanup
```

I ran the code and my LED blinked twice, the first motor (motora) moved forward and backward, but the second motor (motorb) did not move at all. I ran the terminal command "gpio readall" and found that the pins that my second motor are running on (BCM 5, 6) were set to "IN" and both were set to "1".

**terminal output of gpio readall**

[image]

I tried using the GPIO.setup command to change pin 5 and 6 to an output pin but it still stayed the same. I also tried using the terminal command to change the output of the pins from high to low but nothing happened. The GPIO pins appear to be stuck in this mode.

Is there any way to fix these stuck GPIO pins? And am I doing the right thing in this case?

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Maybe try on [raspberry pi SE](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code sets up Motor A by

```
motora = Motor(27, 22)
```

But Motor B is set up by

```
motorb = (5, 6).
```

Shouldn't it be similarly set up by

```
motorb = Motor(5, 6)?
```

Comment: Yes, thank you for catching that, it was a silly mistake by me. Both my motors worked after that.

Comment: It isn't a silly bug.  It is a common for beginners in Python and OOP.  When I read the statement "motora = Motor(27, 22)" I see a motor object with gpio pins 27, 22, of the  "Motor" class with methods "forward", etc.  When I read "motorb = (5, 6 )", I see a tuple "motorb" with two integers 5, 6 (not gpio pin numbers!) .  For this tuple, you can process the two integers, but you cannot ask the tuple to drive the motor for you!  So if you don't see the meaning behind the words of the statements, it is hard for you to catch the difference.